# How to use blogger template in my website

Tags: html, blogs

I want to use one of the blogger free template in my site.When I download ,it is in the  xml format . Is there is any way to use in a site?

Comment: You'll have to take the various templates in that XML file and convert them. They're intended for use in Blogger's system and will contain Blogger-specific templating tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way of doing this. There is a tool name *Webhttrack* which can  download a complete web site along with css, js and images.

To get any blogger template in html:-

- Go to live preview site of that template.
- Give that url to the webhttrack
- It will download this complete template in the html with all css js and image

Get this tool 
https://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/

Comment: That's definitely not a good solution. If you use free template, the xml file is enough to make it work. Just go in the HTML section, and paste the XML code. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you can use the template in your site -

- Log in Blogger dashboard
- Find your Blog in your Dashboard for you want to change template, and       select “Template” in Drop Down menu options.
- Look at the top right corner, you will see Backup / Restore button
  Manage on pop-up windows and click “choose file” button and look for folder that is created after extracted file that you have downloaded.
- Folder may has a .XML file and .TXT file or Internet shortcuts, you should select only XML file.
- Click Upload button. Now upload process  may appear in your screen.
- Now the template will be appear in your blog successfully. Enjoy!

Comment: I want to use it in my own site not in the blogger

Comment: @Suzan Then you'll have to do some converting.